# Unit test Subject: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, observable, subject

After I added a Subject to my service and subscribe to it in my component, all tests for this component are failing with

```
Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined
```

I wonder 
- why *all* tests for this component fail and 
- *how* to test a Subject, its next() method and its subscription like below in Angular 8.

Component:

```
export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  trackSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private trackerService: TrackerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.trackSubscription = this.trackerService.trackSubject.subscribe((state) => {
      console.log(state);
    });
  }

  startTracking() { // called by clicking html button
    this.trackerService.start();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.trackSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Service:

```
export class TrackerService {
   trackSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

   start() {
       // do stuff
       this.trackSubject.next(true);
   }
}
```

Test:

```
describe('TrackerComponent', () => {
  let component: TrackerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TrackerComponent>;
  let trackerService: jasmine.SpyObj<TrackerService>;

  // helper function
  const el = (selector) => fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(selector);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TrackerComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: TrackerService, useFactory: () => spyOnClass(TrackerService) }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrackerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    trackerService = TestBed.get(TrackerService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  // it should show a start button
  it('should show a start button', () => {
    expect(el('[data-test="start-btn"]')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call tracker service when start button clicked', async(() => {
    el('[data-test="start-btn"]').click();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(trackerService.startTracking).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: What line throws this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is because it the subscription has not event taken place once.This we can overcome by adding a check.

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
  if(this.trackSubscription){
    this.trackSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

If the issue is while running test cases

```
 it('calls ngOnDestroy method', () => {
    component.trackSubscription= new Subscription();
    spyOn(component.trackSubscription, 'unsubscribe');
    component.ngOnDestroy();
    expect(component.trackSubscription.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it surely doesn't hurt to check if the subscription exists, but that wasn't my problem - which was failing tests due to the subscribe call in the ngOninit method. See my answer below which includes your test for unsubscribing the subscription, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My tests pass when I do this in the test - but not sure if it makes sense as I'm quite new to unit testing.

In *before each* I create the Subject and the Subscription:

```
component.trackSubscription = new Subscription();
trackerService.trackSubject = new Subject<boolean>();
```

and then the actual tests:

```
it('should subscribe trackSubscription to service subject', () => {
    component.trackSubscription = trackerService.trackSubject.subscribe();
    spyOn(trackerService.trackSubject, 'subscribe');
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(trackerService.trackSubject.subscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('unsubscribes the trackSubscription', () => {

    spyOn(component.trackSubscription, 'unsubscribe');
    component.ngOnDestroy();
    expect(component.trackSubscription.unsubscribe).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

EDIT: Actually just declaring  the Subject and Subscription in before each make all the test pass, but I guess it doesn't hurt to also test the (un)subscribe methods.